# An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting such error, while building `IOS` app in `React Native` project:

> was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain,
>   code=2) Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I read threads in GitHub regarding that [issues](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/109), however didn't find solutions there which could solve my problem. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: hi, i bump into the same issue, would you mind to share with me how you resolve this issue last time?

Comment: Neither of the posted answers were relevant to me. : / I'm still looking for one. The odd thing is that my react native project will build in Xcode, but not CLI.

Comment: I got this error after upgrading from Venture to Sonoma and upgrading Xcode to Version 15.0.1.  To fix it, I just had to open Xcode, then from the menu select Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Simulator.  Once the simulator was open, I could then open it normally with Expo by running npx expo start and hitting 'i'

Answer (score 2):

The cause might be that you have some build files from the previous build which are causing the problem.

Clear the `ios/build/your_project` to trigger a fresh build

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Xcode build folder needed to be cleaned. To fix, in Xcode go to Product | Clean Build Folder

Comment: You can use the shortcut `cmd + shift + k` as well for cleaning the build folder.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case**, the cause was - The build file name was `MyMob.app` but the app it tries to install to the simulator was `mymob.app`.

I solved it by changing the line in `mymob.xcscheme:46`

```
BuildableName = "MyMob.app"
```

```
BuildableName = "mymob.app"
```

---

Log was

```
iinfo Installing "build/mymob/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mymob.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
info Launching "com.mymob.app"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=4):
The request to open "com.mymob.app" failed.
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
        The operation couldn't be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "com.mymob.app"
        Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "com.mymob.app"
```